# Laravel use Get params in Eloquent / DB

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel 5.3.

I have a Repository, and for a specific query, I want to use $_GET params for filtering.

Is there a way to do this like :

```
protected function queryGetAds(Request $request)
{
    return $this->model
        ->select('*')
        ->where('status', '=', 1)
        ->where(function ($q) use ($request) {
            if ($request->from) {
                $q->where('ad_price', '>=', $request->from);
            }
        })
        ->with('user');
}
```

From now, I have an error :

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Repositories\AdRepository::queryGetAds() must be an instance of
>   Illuminate\Http\Request, none given,

Is there a way to do this ? maybe a better way .. ?

I want to add a where when I got a "from" or "to" param in $_GET.

Comment: That sounds like you have imported (using `use`) the wrong class and laravel doesnt find it suitable.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the `$request->from` syntax . Have you tried using `$request->input('field_name')` syntax instead ?

Answer (score 0):

You have following method:

```
protected function queryGetAds(Request $request)
{
    // ...
}
```

Seems like that, you are calling this method by yourself and not passing the required parameter so the error arose. You can either pass the `Illuminate\Http\Request` object as parameter of this method when calling it or just get rid of this parameter from your method and use the `request` global function inside the method to get the request instance, for example:

```
protected function queryGetAds()
{
    $request = request(); // or app('request') or other alternatives
    // Rest of your code should work from here...

    return $this->model ... // Rest of the code ...
}
```

Also, you can pass all the request params in your method like:

```
protected function queryGetAds(Array $requestParams)
{
    return $this->model
    ->select('*')
    ->where('status', '=', 1)
    ->where(function ($q) use ($requestParams) {
        if(isset($requestParams['from'])) {
            $q->where('ad_price', '>=', $requestParams['from']);
        }
    })
    ->with('user');
}
```

And pass the params when calling the method, for example:

```
$someObject->queryGetAds(request()->all());
```